# Magento - change subject in newsletter subscription success email?

Tags: magento

how can i change the subject in newsletter subscription success email?

thanks

EDIT - Version 1.4.0.1

Comment: please include the version number of Magento in your questions.  Email templates changed quite a bit from v1.3 to v1.4 so it helps to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under System>Transactional Emails, you can modify the Newsletter Subscription Success message including subject, and then assign your modified email in System>Configuration>Customers>Newsletter>Success Email Template from the drop-down